# discrete math question with function growth

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Consider three functions, defined recursively, each with the same initial value $V(1)=T(1)=U(1)=3$ but different recurrence relationships for $n>1$:

$$\begin{align}T(n)&=6T\left(\dfrac{n}{2}\right)+c\\
U(n)&=9U\left(\dfrac{n}{3}\right)+c\\
V(n)&=12V\left(\dfrac{n}{4}\right)+c\end{align}$$

Comparing their order of growth gives:

is this answer correct? $$O(T)\supseteq O(U) \supseteq  O(V)$$ 
Thank you very much.

Comment: What is n2? Is this $n^2$?

Comment: n2 is just n2 not n^2

Comment: thank you for looking at this :)

Comment: Ok. so  what is n2? is this $2\times n$?

Comment: i have modified the question and i hope this will make it easier to understand, thank you

Comment: Is there any one can give some hint on this question , thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is correct.

We get the followings :

$$T(n)=\frac{(6c+90)\cdot 6^{\frac{\ln n}{\ln 2}}-6c}{30}$$
$$U(n)=\left(3+\frac{c}{8}\right)n^2-\frac c8$$
$$V(n)=\frac{\left(12c+396\right)\cdot 12^{\frac{\ln n}{\ln 4}}-12c}{132}$$

Note that you can prove these by mathematical induction.

On the other hand, 
$$\lim_{n \to\infty}\frac{6^{\frac{\ln n}{\ln 2}}}{n^2}=\infty$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2}{12^{\frac{\ln n}{\ln 4}}}=\infty$$

Hence, we now know that we reach the answer you wrote.